# Checking that all questions have been answered in a mechanical turk survey

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

**Background**

I am setting up a data annotation task on mechanical turk. The user has has to give scores for pairs of sentences. Each pair of sentences has a table with 7 radio buttons. For each such table, the user MUST give an answer.

**Problem**

There are 194 such tables in the document, so it's easy to miss one. The user is not warned that ones of the questions has not been answered if he/she missed one or more when they hit submit, forcing us to reject their input because of a simple omission.

**Restrictions**

Unfortunately, we do not have the option of submitting each table as a separate hit because:

a) We need to know what the scores are for the complete data set for a single user.

b) We have quality control questions which the user must answer, and they cannot be informed which ones these are.

**Question**

Is there a simple way to make sure that users answer each question either by:

a) Raising a warning if they have not answered all questions? If so, how is this done?

b) Presenting each table on a separate page with users having to click "next" to get the next table, in which case it is still possible to miss one but less likely (as you don't have to scroll down a large page)? If so, how is this done?

Thanks in advance for any help or solutions towards solving this problem.

Comment: Are you posting this to mTurk as a question form (using the Amazon XML structures) or as an external question (hosted on your own web server)?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [mTurk API docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/2008-08-02/AWSMturkAPI/) and specifically look at the [QuestionFormStructure](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/2008-08-02/AWSMturkAPI/index.html?ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html) section.

If you format your Questions and add the IsRequired flag, which defaults to false if you don't explicitly set it.

```
<Question>
  <QuestionIdentifier>my_question_id</QuestionIdentifier>
  <DisplayName>My Question</DisplayName>
  <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
  <QuestionContent>
    [...]
  </QuestionContent>
  <AnswerSpecification>
    [...]
  </AnswerSpecification>
</Question>
```

However, if you have 194 of these tables in a single HIT, you may be better off doing it as an external question so you can add some javascript to help people navigate to the parts they missed more quickly.